# Pass a String to a Class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, static

I'm using the `streaming_audio_flutter_demo` project on Github. https://github.com/suragch/streaming_audio_flutter_demo

This has a class that provides a `ValueListenableBuilder` and a slider along with play and pause controls for my app.

The only problem is, I'd like to change the example URL to my own;

```
static const url = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3';
```

But I'm not sure how to pass it to the class from the main page of my app. Here's the code for the PageManager class;

```
 class PageManager {
  final progressNotifier = ValueNotifier<ProgressBarState>(
    ProgressBarState(
      current: Duration.zero,
      buffered: Duration.zero,
      total: Duration.zero,
    ),
  );
  final buttonNotifier = ValueNotifier<ButtonState>(ButtonState.paused);

  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  static const url = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3';

  PageManager() {
    _init();
  }

  void _init() async {
    // initialize the song
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    await _audioPlayer.setUrl(url);        
  }  
}
```

The String I need to pass looks like this;

```
_current?.path
```

So how can I access the

```
static const url = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3';
```

from the main page of my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
static const url = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3';

  PageManager() {
    _init();
  }
```

with

```
String url; // don't use const variable!
PageManager({this.url="You can set a default URL here"}){
   _init();
}
```

now you can use it in your `main.dart` as follow:

```
_pageManager = PageManager(url: "YOUR URL");
```

let me know the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a constructor.
In `PageManager` class add this function:

```
String url;
PageManager(this.url);

then you can define an object related to this class as follow:
PageManager pageManager = new PageManager("YOUR URL");
```

Comment: Heres the error I got with the PageManager(){_init();} ; Non-nullable instance field 'url' must be initialized. "PageManager" is in red.

Comment: would you please share your code completely?

Comment: It's at this link but I think this may work; PageManager(this.url) {
    _init();
  }

Comment: Sorry here's the link; https://github.com/suragch/streaming_audio_flutter_demo

Comment: I update my answer based on your code, please check it out.